# Web Analytics - List Items

Tags: list-item

I have a list of 50 faqs.  Is there a way to pull the number of times an faq is accessed in Sharepoint 2010. If so how.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint auditing allows tracking of various activities for users, such as Viewing, Check-In, Deleting, etc. (have a look here https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/pages/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx or http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx).

In practice, you have different levels to enable audition, such at the level of either Content Types (strong recomand to use those!) or list/libraries via the Information Management Policies or simply at the site collection level.

But enabling this should also be accompanied by planning, as it does get enabled at Site Collection level and generates a lot of data, with regards to what kind of events are you monitoring. Only enable it when needed for those events of importance. Consider also Triming periodically these reports.

After a while, you could visualize those reports, example http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx